# How to get contents from a local text file to print on individual lines in a html template (Python/Flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnUyS.png)I'm looking to get posts from a user to post on individual lines. At the moment I take in a name, email and comment, pass it to the app.py file and store it to a text file. I return a name, email, comment and  the time of the comment. When I read the file and pass in back to the html template the posts display one after the other (see the screenshot included), and im trying to have them display one below each other. f.write("\n") results in the actual text file skipping a line however this does not occur in the template.

**form_action.html**

```
<html>
<div align = "center">

<body style="background-color: #3DC247;">

<head>
<title>Conor McGregor</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align = "center">
<h1 style="font-family:verdana;">I AM EL CHAPO</h1>
<div align = "center">
<h2 style="font-family:verdana;">YOU'LL DO NUTIN.</h2>

<div align = "center">
<h2 style="font-family:verdana;">Disscusion Page</h2>


 <body>
     <div id="container">
         <div class="title">
            <h3 style="font-family:verdana;">Please fill in your details    
           below and your comment to join the discussion</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('hello') }}">
              <label for="yourname" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
           enter your name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br /><br>

              <label for="youremail" style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
           enter your email:</label>
              <input type="text" name="youremail" /><br /><br>

              <label for="yourcomment"style="font-family:verdana;">Please 
           enter your comment:</label>
              <input type="textarea" name="yourcomment" rows="4" cols="50">               
              <input type="submit" /><br>
            </form>


        </div>  
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      <div id="container">
         <div class="title">
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana;"><p>Comments</p></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

                    {{details}}

        </div>  

      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**app.py**

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
 import time
 import datetime


 # Initialize the Flask application
 app = Flask(__name__)

 # Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
 @app.route('/')
 def form():
    return render_template('form_submit.html')

 @app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST','GET'])
 def hello():
   global time

   name=request.form['yourname']
   email=request.form['youremail']
   comment=request.form['yourcomment']
   comment_time=time.strftime("%a-%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

   f = open ("user+comments.txt","a")

   f.write(name + '  ' + email + '   ' + comment + "  " + comment_time)
   f.write('\n')
   f.close()

    with open("user+comments.txt", "r") as f:

    details = f.read()
    f.close()

    return render_template('form_action.html', details = details, name=name,   
    email=email, comment=comment, comment_time=comment_time)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML does not know what `\n` is. You can fix this in two ways.

1. **Convert `str` details to `list` details**

   ```
   details = f.read().split('\n')
   ```

   This converts the `str` object to `list` object. You could print it in your template using

   ```
   {% for detail in details %}
        {{detail}}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. **Replace `\n` with `<br>`**

   ```
   details = f.read().replace('\n','<br>')
   ```

   and then print it as `{{ details|safe }}` in `form_action.html`.
   It is important that you use the [safe filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#controlling-autoescaping). The `<br>` would be escaped without it and rendered as simple text.